# iOS 8 video progress bar not visible

Tags: objective-c, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an iOS app in which I am trying to show videos using `MPMoviePlayerController`.
The code is very simple and working fine on all the devices with all iOS version greater than 6.0.

But the problem is on iOS 8 and 8.1, the progress bar of the video is not visible as shown in below image.

[image]

I dont understand why this is happening or is this iOS 8 bug.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too in my app, which supports several iOS versions but this issue is indeed only visible on iOS 8.

My code toggles the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `controlStyle` between `MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded` and `MPMovieControlStyleNone`, and this is triggered using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`. I have to admit that I programmatically rotate my player, I do not rotate the application; this is maybe a root of this issue. I display the controls in portrait, and hide them in landscape.

I apparently solved it in two steps. I did not isolated this issue in a simple app so my apologies if the solution is not accurate for everyone.

**First**, the dirty part, *and perhaps not necessary for everybody who encounter this issue*, I parse some of the player subviews to look after the `MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView` view, in order to force its visibility or invisibility.

```
// Helps to hide or show the controls over the player
// The reason of this method is we are programmatically rotating the player view, while not rotating the application
// On latest iOS, this leads to misbehavior that we have to take into account
-(void)showMPMoviePlayerControls:(BOOL)show
{
    self.player.controlStyle = (show ? MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded : MPMovieControlStyleNone);
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8"))
    {
        // Workaround to avoid persistence of empty control bar
        for(UIView *subView in self.player.backgroundView.superview.superview.subviews)
        {
            if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView")]) {
            subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                subView.alpha = (show ? 1.0 : 0.0);
                subView.hidden = (show ? NO : YES);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this was not enough. Probably because the portrait mode has several orientations (`UIDeviceOrientationPortrait`, `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp`, ...) that trigger the notification, hence the control style change request.

So the **second step** of my fix was to handle the fact that it is not necessary to change the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `controlStyle` if we are already in the correct screen orientation.
In my case, the solution was to verify that the status bar was hidden, as I hide it in landscape:

```
// Set embedded controls only when there is a transition to portrait, i.e. if status bar was hidden
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) {
    [self showMPMoviePlayerControls:YES];
    // and we show the status bar here
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Maybe the point here is that we should not set the `controlStyle` if it is already set to the wanted value.

As this solved the problem for me, I stopped my investigations. Anyway I suppose that it is probably simpler in most cases. Certainly linked to the fact that the `controlStyle` is changed at the wrong time, or changed but was already in the wanted state.

Comment: @Johann....thanks for reply....but in my case i found that it is problem with repainting the view...so I just load a blank view controller before playing the video for 0.5 sec and removed it....and things were working as expected.