# MPMoviePlayer progress bar disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, mpmoviewcontroller

Using MPMoviePlayerController, if I make a fullscreen video with ControlStyleFullscreen, then I close it, then I instantiate a new one, the progress bar is gone from the controls in iOS 8 in the second one. This happens 100% of the time. Has anyone else encountered this? Is this an iOS bug? It still happens in 8.2.

Another way to reproduce: using an embedded video with ControlStyleEmbedded, if I run the following code, the progress bar also disappears. Note that the code is intended to force the controls to show after a programmatic pause:

```
    [self.videoPlayer pause];   
    self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
```

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you can provide more code.

Comment: I probably had a similar issue. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28612499/1844385), I hope it will help you.